# How Can I get the last inserted sequence value for respective to a web session in JSP and Oracle?

Tags: oracle, jsp

First of all I beg to request you, please do not treat this as duplicate.
I have seen all the threads for this issue but none was of my type.
I am developing an online registration system using JBOSS 6 and Oracle 11g. I want to give every registrant a unique form number sequentially.
 For this, I think oracle's **sequence_name.nextval** for a primary key field is best for inserting a unique yet sequential number and for retrieving the same I would use **sequence_name.currval**. Till this I hope, it's ok.
But will this ensure parity if two or more concurrent users submits the web form simultaneously? (I mean will there be any overlap of interchange of value among the concurrent users?)
More precisely, is it session dependent?

Let me give two hypothetical situations so that matter becomes clearer.

Say there are two users, user1 and user2 trying to register at the same time sitting at Newyork and Paris respectively. The max(form_no) is say 100 before they click the submit button. Now, in the code I have written say

```
      insert into member(....) values(seq_form_no.nextval,....).
```

Now since the two users will invoke the same query sitting at two different terminals will they get their own sequential id or user1 will get user2's or vice-versa? Hope I made the issue clear. See, the sequence will be unique, I know, but I want to associate the ids inserted respectively.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sequence_name.currval does not return anything if you do not call nextval before. curval is a value generated by prev. nextval call. You can also use `insert into member(....) values(seq_form_no.nextval,....) returning id into ?`. So a single insert call can also return generated id.

Comment: returning clause works in PL/SQL, but can you make sure whether it would work in JSP code also! @ ibre5041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand. But simply said, a `SENQUENCE` ensure *uniqueness* of the generated number among concurrent transactions/connections. Unless if the sequence was created with the `CYCLE` option, from within a transaction, you can rely on a strictly monotonically increasing (resp. decreasing) numbering. But not from the absence of gap (probably what you where expecting when talking about "sequential numbers").

Worth mentioning that sequence numbers *never* go backward. When someone acquires a value, it is "consumed" from the sequence and will never get back inside (beside `CYCLE`) -- even if you rollback the current transaction.

From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) (emphasis mine):

> When a sequence number is generated, the sequence is incremented, independent of the transaction committing or rolling back. If two users concurrently increment the same sequence, then the sequence numbers each user acquires may have gaps, because sequence numbers are being generated by the other user. **One user can never acquire the sequence number generated by another user.** After a sequence value is generated by one user, that user can continue to access that value regardless of whether the sequence is incremented by another user.

---

My JSP is a little bit ... "rusty", but something *like* that will work as expected:

```
<sql:update dataSource="${ds}" var="result">
INSERT INTO member(....) values(seq_form_no.nextval,....);
</sql:update>

<sql:query dataSource="${ds}" var="last_inserted_member_id">
SELECT seq_form_no.currval FROM DUAL;
</sql:query>
```

Comment: Thanks Sylvain Leroux. Please review my post which I edited recently to make the issue more clear.

Comment: Quoting your edit @samlancer : _"two users will invoke the same query sitting at two different terminals will they get their own sequential id or user1 will get user2's or vice-versa"_ You call `nextval` to acquire a value. `currval` on a sequence will return _your_ last acquired value on that sequence. There is no way for two different users to get back the same value. Nor for an user to access the value obtained by an other user.

Comment: @Tiny 10 years old ? Well ... that about the last time I used JSP I think. Would you be kind enough to edit the answer to rewrite the example as "modern" JSP ? I think that could be of greatest help, both for the OP and for my own education...

Comment: Techniques apart, l was rather concerned about the returning ID after INSERT respect to the user who invoked the INSERT from his/her terminal. If that is ensured from the technologies, as confirmed by Sylvain, then I am happy to go. Thanks once again to all contributors.